# Specifying blob type over websocket from c++

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket, blob

From c++ I'm sending the binary representation of a png file over websocket to javascript where I use it like this:

```
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    if (event.data instanceof Blob) {
        var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
        viewerImage.src = imageUrl;
    }
};
```

This successfully shows the image in the browser. However, *right-click > Open lmage in new tab* shows an URL like "blob:null/a55b72db-1ea8-42aa-b78f-621d8b289849" and the content is the binary data of the file represented as utf-text or something.

My question is, whether there is a way to change the blob type to *image/png*. Should I prepend some information to the png file before I send it?

Comment: I am not sure but what you create the blob yourself and add the uint8array into it instead of accepting the blob 
` var blob = new Blob([binaryDataArray], {type: 'image/png'});
var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); `

Comment: Good idea. It also shows the image and the generated URLs look exactly the same as before. However, on opening in new tab, chrome shows a kind of empty square instead printing the binary data.

Comment: Hmm maybe the browser treats the blob:// urls differently, i don't know